# Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:prereleaseCompileClasspath'

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I am trying to build an app I clone it from Github [CloudStream 3](https://github.com/LagradOst/CloudStream-3) but it always fails, I am new to android and I couldn't figure out the problem when I try to build the project it show this message:

```
> Configure project :app
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lint'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:prereleaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find appcompat-1.4.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat/1.4.1/appcompat-1.4.1.aar
   > Could not find extension-okhttp-2.16.1.aar (com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.16.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/exoplayer/extension-okhttp/2.16.1/extension-okhttp-2.16.1.aar
   > Could not find constraintlayout-2.1.3.aar (androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/constraintlayout/constraintlayout/2.1.3/constraintlayout-2.1.3.aar
   > Could not find appcompat-resources-1.4.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.4.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/appcompat-resources/1.4.1/appcompat-resources-1.4.1.aar

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

the Gradle setting for the project is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.21"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}

def tmpFilePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/work/_temp/keystore/"
def allFilesFromDir = new File(tmpFilePath).listFiles()
def prerelaseStoreFile = null
if (allFilesFromDir != null) {
    prerelaseStoreFile = allFilesFromDir.first()
}


android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        prerelease {
            if (prerelaseStoreFile != null) {
                storeFile = file(prerelaseStoreFile)
                storePassword System.getenv("SIGNING_STORE_PASSWORD")
                keyAlias System.getenv("SIGNING_KEY_ALIAS")
                keyPassword System.getenv("SIGNING_KEY_PASSWORD")
            }
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lagradost.cloudstream3"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30

        versionCode 42
        versionName "2.6.9"

        resValue "string", "app_version",
                "${defaultConfig.versionName}${versionNameSuffix ?: ""}"

        buildConfigField("String", "BUILDDATE", "new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(\"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm\").format(new java.util.Date(" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "L));")

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        kapt {
            includeCompileClasspath = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        prerelease {
            applicationIdSuffix ".prerelease"
            buildConfigField("boolean", "BETA", "true")
            signingConfig signingConfigs.prerelease
            versionNameSuffix '-PRE'
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        freeCompilerArgs = ['-Xjvm-default=compatibility']
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.json:json:20180813'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    //implementation "io.karn:khttp-android:0.1.2" //okhttp instead
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.12.3"

    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0"

    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.12.0'

    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.0.0'

    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'

    // implementation "androidx.leanback:leanback-paging:1.1.0-alpha09"

    // Exoplayer
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.16.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-cast:2.16.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-mediasession:2.16.1"
    //implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-leanback:2.14.0"

    // Bug reports
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-core:5.8.4"
    implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:5.8.4"

    compileOnly "com.google.auto.service:auto-service-annotations:1.0"
    //either for java sources:
    annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0"
    //or for kotlin sources (requires kapt gradle plugin):
    kapt "com.google.auto.service:auto-service:1.0"

    // subtitle color picker
    implementation 'com.jaredrummler:colorpicker:1.1.0'

    //run JS
    implementation 'org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4'

    // TorrentStream
    //implementation 'com.github.TorrentStream:TorrentStream-Android:2.7.0'

    // Downloading
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1"
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1"

    // Networking
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-dnsoverhttps:4.9.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-okhttp:2.16.1'

    // Util to skip the URI file fuckery 
    implementation "com.github.tachiyomiorg:unifile:17bec43"

    // API because cba maintaining it myself
    implementation "com.uwetrottmann.tmdb2:tmdb-java:2.6.0"


    // debugImplementation because LeakCanary should only run in debug builds.
    // debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.7'

    // for shimmer when loading
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
}
```

what should I do to make It build correctly?
thank you for your time.

Comment: try add `mavenCentral()` repository

Comment: I tried but it didn't work

Comment: with the exoplayer, try changing for a bigger pakage like: implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.X.X' what happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, the latest version for exoplayer is 2.16.1 but I tried to downgrade it but it still not working

Comment: Ok, but pay attention, the package I'm saying you to try has the final: `exoplayer-core:2.16.1`, instead of the one you're trying to use: `extension-okhttp:2.16.1`. Have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turns out that I need to downgrade the libraries I used the 1.3.1 version instead of 1.4.1 for the `androidx.appcompat` library , the version 2.15.1 instead of 2.16.1 for the `com.google.android.exoplayer` and the version 2.1.1 instead of 2.1.3 for the `androidx.constraintlayout`

Comment: Thanks man, it solved my errors, But is there a link for how to migrate from 2.9 to latest?

Comment: Migrate what? you didn't specify

Comment: I wanted to migrate from exoplayer 2.9 to 2.15. alot of my functions got deprecated. So i need help

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything about migrating from 2.9 to 2.15 but I recommend you start from the official docs [link](https://exoplayer.dev/)